# What's the type hint for an array?

Tags: python, arrays, type-hinting

For most collections we can do:

```py
from typing import List, Tuple, etc
```

Is there a hint for `array`? As in:

```py
arr = array.array('i')
```

Comment: There is no built-in `array`.  Do you mean `List`?

Comment: @Samwise There is, it's just not very commonly used.

Comment: If anyone is wondering about what array: 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html

Comment: @Samwise, not sure if it's 'built-in'. What I meant was `array.array('i')` and such.

Comment: You can use `array.array` directly in a type hint.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks, that's the answer I was looking for!

Comment: You can use any types directly. The `List` and such in `typing` were made since the built-in types originally couldn't be subscripted. They can now though, so a lot of `typing` is being depreacted.

Comment: @Carcigenicate `array.array[int]` seems to work. Nice! Do you know what min version of Python I need for this to work?

Comment: `array.array[int]` should not work. I've never used `array` before (it's extremely niche), but from my understanding, it only holds integers, so `[int]` would be redundant, and when I tried it just now, I was told that `array` isn't subscriptable (`TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`).

Comment: @Carcigenicate You're right. It's not subscriptable. I wish it was. Arrays can hold more than just integers.

Comment: I guess ya, they can also hold floats, and it may be helpful to be able to statically differentiate between different array types. Maybe in the future. `array` is likely low on their priority list.

Comment: @Carcigenicate no, it basically can hold any of the generic C numeric types, plus a single unicode character. But basically, in interacts with the Python level through `float` and `int` and `str`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Carcigenicate pointed out, you can use `array.array` directly as a type annotation. However, you can't use `array.array[int]` or `array.array[float]` to specify the type of the elements.

If you need to do this, my suggestion is to use [`MutableSequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSequence) from `collections.abc`, since arrays implement all of the necessary operations: `__len__`, `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__contains__`, `__iter__`, etc.

```py
from collections.abc import MutableSequence

arr: MutableSequence[float] = array.array('f')
```