# type hinting an array

Tags: python, arrays, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Consider the following minimal example:

```
from array import array


def foo(arr: array) -> None:
    print(arr)
```

I have a function which takes an `array` argument.
My project is statically typed and uses [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).
Mypy complains that:
`Mypy: Missing type parameters for generic type "array"`.

Could you help me understand how am I supposed to type hint the argument? I can't seem to find documentation on the subject. I can't understand why would mypy decide this is a generic type.

To clarify, to my understanding, the type hint I used works, but mypy still complains as it considers it as a generic type, and wants the type of the "elements". Am I missing something, or is it a bug in mypy?

Related to this:
[What's the type hint for an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67775113/whats-the-type-hint-for-an-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the standard library is not type annotated. `mypy` is using the stubs for the standard library from the [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed) project (which along with the standard library, also contains annotations for popular third-party library as provided by various contributers). For the [`array` module](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/array.pyi#L14), you can see that it is type annotated as generic:

```
import sys
from typing import Any, BinaryIO, Generic, Iterable, MutableSequence, Tuple, TypeVar, Union, overload
from typing_extensions import Literal

_IntTypeCode = Literal["b", "B", "h", "H", "i", "I", "l", "L", "q", "Q"]
_FloatTypeCode = Literal["f", "d"]
_UnicodeTypeCode = Literal["u"]
_TypeCode = Union[_IntTypeCode, _FloatTypeCode, _UnicodeTypeCode]

_T = TypeVar("_T", int, float, str)

typecodes: str

class array(MutableSequence[_T], Generic[_T]):
    typecode: _TypeCode
    itemsize: int
    @overload
    def __init__(self: array[int], typecode: _IntTypeCode, __initializer: bytes | Iterable[_T] = ...) -> None: ...
    @overload
    def __init__(self: array[float], typecode: _FloatTypeCode, __initializer: bytes | Iterable[_T] = ...) -> None: ...
    @overload
    def __init__(self: array[str], typecode: _UnicodeTypeCode, __initializer: bytes | Iterable[_T] = ...) -> None: ...
    @overload
    def __init__(self, typecode: str, __initializer: bytes | Iterable[_T] = ...) -> None: ...
    def append(self, __v: _T) -> None: ...

    ...
```

The solution is to use `MutableSequence` as noted as answered in the question you linked to. Note, since Python 3.9+, `typing.MutableSequence` (along with things like `typing.List` and `typing.Dict`) have been deprecated, and the types themselves support generics, so use `import collections` and `collections.abc.MutableSequence`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and educational answer.